# VBA Copy ID's from one worksheet if no match is made

Tags: vba, copy, find, match, no-duplicates

I do not have 10 reputation, so I'm unable to uploaded images, which would make this much, MUCH easier to explain... i posted a table example over to Mr. Excel forum here: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/833202-visual-basic-applications-find-non-match-criteria-ws2-copy-criteria-ws1.html

I have two worksheets. I need to find Employee ID's in "Sheet2" that match the Employee ID's in "Sheet1". If "Sheet2" has an ID that is not in "Sheet1", then I need to copy specific cells from the said row of "Sheet2" over to "Sheet1".

On top of that, when copying over, I need to make sure that a whole row inserts for the copied cells in order for the previous $amounts to be in the correct spot (see the post in Mr. Excel). This probably makes no sense. If only I could upload an image...

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyNonMatches()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws1Range As Range, ws2range As Range
Dim ws1Long As Long, ws2long As Long

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

With ws1
ws1Long = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With

Set ws1Range = ws1.Range("C3", "C" & ws1Long)

With ws2
ws2long = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With

Set ws2range = ws2.Range("C3", "C" & ws2long)

'Now I need to compare the ranges 'ws1Range' with 'ws2Range' and if 'ws2Range' has ID's that...
'...are not included in 'ws1Range', then I need to copy over info from Columns A to C from the row that had no match over to 'Sheet1'.

???????????????????

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Sub CopyNonMatches()

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim vIDs1 As Variant, vData As Variant
Dim i As Long

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

vIDs1 = ws1.Range("C2", ws1.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value
vData = ws2.Range("A2", ws2.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value

For i = 1 To UBound(vData, 1)
    If IsError(Application.Match(vData(i, 3), vIDs1, 0)) Then
        ws1.Rows(8).Insert
        ws1.Range("A8:C8").Value = Array(vData(i, 1), vData(i, 2), vData(i, 3))
    End If
Next i
```

End Sub